# Rust autocomplete doesn't work in Vim

Tags: vim, rust, vundle

I installed Rust and the [Rust vim plugin](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust.vim#using-vundle), but autocomplete does not work.

- I'm using a nightly version of Rust (`rustc 1.10.0-dev (992bb1332 2016-05-12)`.
- I used Vundle to install the plugin
- I'm running Debian GNU/Linux sid

**.vimrc**

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'mattn/vim-particle'
Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
Plugin 'rust-lang/rust.vim'

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Why is autocomplete not working?

Comment: More importantly, why do you expect autocompletion in the first place?

Comment: @romainl Because it helps to keep the time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Rust vim plugin doesn't support autocomplete. [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) has autocomplete for [Rust](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#rust-semantic-completion) (powered by [racer](https://github.com/phildawes/racer)).

Answer (score 4):

YouCompleteMe is a bit complicated to install and heavy, but is probably great if you have many languages you want to autocomplete. In my case, [VimRacer](https://github.com/racer-rust/vim-racer) really does the job!

Here's how to install it:

1. Install [Racer](https://github.com/racer-rust/racer).
2. Execute `rustup component add rust-src` to get the Rust source code.
3. Install [VimRacer](https://github.com/racer-rust/vim-racer) using the way you prefer (Vundle or other) and follow the README.

Comment: I installed this - after some struggling - but now when I do C-x C-o - I get the suggestions and the first one is inserted by default ... :O Which is super uncomfortable ... can we make the window appears and nothing is pre-selected?